# Automatically calculate current year in criteria string of CountIFs statement

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, criteria, countif

I want to count certain values using an excel formula.  I am using `CountIFs` but the problem is that my value has the current year as a part of the string. For example one of the values are CMS 2015. I was wondering if there was a way to incorporate a function in the criteria string so that it will automatically calculate the year? Also, I would like to search for the same string only one year ahead of the current (eg. CMS 2016). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something like `"CMS " & YEAR(NOW())+1`?

Comment: No worries, I'll pop it into an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the calculated date like so:

```
="CMS " & YEAR(NOW()) +1
```

Comment: How would I count both the current year and one year ahead? Like if it is CMS 2015 or CMS 2016 it would be apart of the count?

Comment: My understanding is that the `COUNTIF` formula is an `AND` construct ie you wont be able to use an or. You'll probably need to use `SUMPRODUCT` instead.

Comment: You can use this formula =`SUM(COUNTIFS(Criteria_range,"CSM "&YEAR(NOW())+{0,1}))` - the {0,1} gives you this year and next - you can add other criteria as required